# Javascript code to extract POST variables in html

Tags: javascript, html, variables, post

Is there any code or script with which we can extract POST variables and the corresponding data in html page?

Comment: No.  The POST variables only exist when they're sent to the server.  You need to write server-side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The browser doesn't make the POST data that was used to request the current page available to client-side JavaScript.

You would need to process them server side (which you could do with JavaScript, but the specifics would depend on which server side JavaScript implementation and any HTTP server libraries you were using) and then inject them into the page when it is generated.

Comment: user3126593 use server side language like PHP.

Comment: ohk.. thanks everyone... will try using php..